# How to use multithreading for gremlin edge creation

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have been working on tinkerpop gremlin graph, and lately i can able to perform lots of stuff with that, now i'm struck at one point where i'm trying to process many thousands of vertices and edges, it takes around one hour to complete the process, how can i apply parallelStream() operation to this following part:

```
for(String s : somelist){
  String[] ss = s.split(",");
  graphTraversal().addEdge(ss[0], ss[1]);
}
```

That "somelist" contains the information for each edge's source and target vertices(~size of 65,000).

Comment: what graph database are you using?

Comment: TinkerGraph @stephenmallette

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinkerGraph technically isn't completely thread-safe for writes. You might hit some problems depending on what you're loading and how you are loading it. I can't say exactly what those problems are and what you might need to do to avoid them, but we definitely haven't tested TinkerGraph that way.

That said, 65,000 edges in the format you're specifying in your sample code should not take an hour to load into TinkerGraph even in a single threaded mode of operation. That sounds a bit excessive. I assume your sample code is not what you are actually executing as that is not valid Gremlin syntax, so it's hard to say what the problem might be.

Comment: Actually, thats just a method call, where the method performs this:- g.V().has("id", ss0).out("Link").has("id", ss1).fold()
          .coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addE("BelongsTo").from(__.V(v4)).to(__.V(v3))).iterate(); Could that be done in more faster way?

Comment: Did you create an index on "id" for your vertices? also...i think you can just do `from(v4).to(v3)` - no need to re-lookup those vertices which is cheap, but you're constructing extra steps for no significant reason.

Comment: no, i haven't created an index, i'm just making use of the default id created by gremlin itself, i'm concerned for duplicates only, thats why didnt care much for the index, also i don't know whether will it speed up my program?

Comment: `has("id", ss0)` is not how you look up by the default id created by TinkerGraph. in that case you are referring to a property called "id". If you want the identifier created by the graph then you need to do `g.V(ss0)` or `has(id, ss0)`. If "id" however is a property that you have assigned then you should create an index for it otherwise you'll be iterating all vertices for each lookup.

Comment: i get it now, sorry.. i do have external id assigned to it, how do you create an index for that, any suggestions pls?

Comment: my case is very simple, all am doing is creating a vertex(before adding edges) with an id from a list itself(like this):-    Vertex v1 = g.V().has("id", id).fold()
    .coalesce(__.unfold(),
      __.addV().property(T.label, typeName).property("id", id).property("name", name)).next();

Comment: TinkerGraph allows you to assign ids so either make your "id" property the graph id with `property(T.id, yourId)` and then lookups with `g.V(yourId)` will be fast OR if you must use `property("id",yourId)` then create an index `graph.createIndex("id",Vertex.class)`.

Comment: i don't get it, why do we assign Vertex.class to the id ? and when do we do that?

Comment: when you create your graph create an index. you'r not assigning `Vertex.class` to "id", you're saying "create an index for vertices for the property name called 'id'" - hence the method name `createIndex()`.